# SQL query to Break on row into multiple row based on some delimiter

Tags: postgresql

I have a table named `test' which has following structure.

```
category        key                                                 value    
name           real_name:Brad,nick_name:Brady,name_type:small        NOVALUE 
other          description                                           cool
```

But I want to break `key` column into multiple rows based on `,` delimiter and value after `:` delimiter should be a part of value column where value is equal to `NOVALUE`. So output should look like:

```
category        key               value
name           real_name          Brad
name           nick_name          Brady
name           name_type          small
other          description        cool
```

How to write `sql` query for this . I am using `postgresql`.

Any help ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't only  want to split a string into multiple columns based on some delimiter.  Instead i want to break into multiple row based on one delimiter and then split each row into multiple columns based on some other delimiter.

Comment: You shouldn't be storing delimited values in the first place

Answer (score 1):

You can use `string_to_array` and unnest to do this:

```
select ts.category, 
       split_part(key_value, ':', 1) as key,
       split_part(key_value, ':', 2) as value
from test ts
  cross join lateral unnest(string_to_array(ts.key, ',')) as t (key_value)
where ts.value = 'NOVALUE'

union all

select category, 
       key, 
       value
from test
where value <> 'NOVALUE';
```

SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/6f1e6/1

Comment: Thanks man, U are a genius. i tested, this is exactly what i wanted. Thanks again.

Comment: Hi @a_horse_with_no_name , I have changed the question a little bit. I don't know whether it is stupid to ask you again or not but i am struggling into it. and it needs to be quickly so i don't want to spent much time into it. Could you please help me in that ? Thanks.

Comment: @Rajeevkumar: it's not considered nice to change the question after you have received an answer. I have updated my answer

Comment: Sorry for the same, i understand that. actually i had come up with the different approach but was not happy with that. so i thought you will be able to give better solution.  and thanks again man with edited answer.  by the way i am updating my answer below. you can review and tell me whether it'd good or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
 select category, 
       split_part(key_value, ':', 1) as key,
       case  when  value = 'NOVALUE' then split_part(key_value, ':', 2) else value end 
from test
  cross join lateral unnest(string_to_array(key, ',')) as t (key_value)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.